# Program to turn TouchPad On AND Off

Tags: touchpad, xinput

I have a ThinkPad Edge E520 and am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I would like to have an executable file on my desktop which can easily turn on or off my TouchPad and TrackPoint:

```
xinput list
...
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Through my own research I have created two files, one to turn it on, and one to turn it off.  I cannot, however, figure out how to combine these two programs into one program to turn these input off if they are on, and vice versa.  I've been playing around with *if* statements, but can only get the program to always turn the inputs on or always turn them off.

Here is my program to turn the inputs on:

```
xinput set-prop 15 "Device Enabled" 1
xinput set-prop 13 "Device Enabled" 1
```

and the other to turn them off:

```
xinput set-prop 15 "Device Enabled" 0
xinput set-prop 13 "Device Enabled" 0
```

Could anyone help me combine these into a single program?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are `if` statements possible in bash?

Comment: Huh. It looks like you can. I'll post an answer, since I can't do the code here.

Comment: Do you know the condition you need? Like `if prop 15 "Device Enabled" 0`?

Comment: Play around with `xinput query-state 15/13`. That might get you closer to what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using another approach to toggle the touchpad state: `synclient`. You could as well use your xinput commands instead, but I prefer synclient.

I'm using the following script, assigned to a hotkey, to toggle my touchpad on/off:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$(synclient | grep TouchpadOff | grep 1)" ]; then
    synclient TouchpadOff=1
else
    synclient TouchpadOff=0
fi
```

How does it work?

When executing `synclient` without any arguments, it returns a list of all settings and their current state. From this list, the script greps the option "TouchpadOff", which is - who would've guessed it - 1 if the touchpad is off and 0 elsewise.

To check this, I used test's `-z` switch (following string empty), combined with another grep, which evaluates to `true`, if the touchpad is off. In this case, it again calls `synclient` with an argument telling it to set the option to "1", thereby disabling the touchpad.

Elsewise, the script does the opposite and reenables the touchpad.

---

Note that synclient doesn't store settings permanently, so if you don't do anything else, your toucpad will always be enabled on boot.

Comment: If you combine this with a udev rule, you can automatically turn your touchpad off/on when an external mouse is connected/disconnected, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this script to switch the touchpad status.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
id=$(xinput | grep -i "TouchPad" | cut -f 2 | cut -d= -f 2)
status=$(xinput --list-props $id | grep "Device Enabled" | cut -f 3)
if [ $status -eq 1 ]; then
    xinput --disable $id
else
    xinput --enable $id
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a little script that you can try. Run it twice from Terminal to see if it can disable and re-enable device 15. If it works, I'll edit in 13.
[Test](http://www.weebly.com/uploads/1/1/5/4/11540598/test)

Comment: Ugh. Nevermind. I messed something up. I need to fix it.

Comment: What's the current status of this answer? Should the script be added? Did it not work out, and the answer should be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Seppi!

Your script worked perfectly.  I added in one of my original lines to also enable/disable the TrackPoint as well.

```bash
if [ -z "$(synclient | grep TouchpadOff | grep 1)" ]; then
    synclient TouchpadOff=1
    xinput set-prop 15 "Device Enabled" 0
else
    synclient TouchpadOff=0
    xinput set-prop 15 "Device Enabled" 1
fi
```